# Correcting the double summation formula written in pseudo-code

Tags: python

[image]

I have to implement the formula above in python, but I am having a difficulty fully understanding it. I wrote a pseudo code for doing this and I really need someone to correct it.

**Given Info**

So, I am running this code in a parallel corpus for Machine translation that consists of S sentence pairs (f
(s), e(s)), where 1 ≤ s ≤ S. So f(s) and e(s) represents s'th sentence in the corpus in `f:foreign language` and `e: english`. `e_x` is the x'th words in the sentence `e(s)`

I understood this formula as the following pseudo-code:

```
for a fixed english word e_x in all sentences:
    for all foreign word f_y in the sentence where f_y and e_x appears together:
        Z += apply the count in <.. I have the function for calculating this..>
```

Am I understanding this formula correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like `Z_{e_x}` is the computation of `Z` for whatever `e_x` is. So the formula you have is just for a single english word `e_x`. So you'd probably need a vector/map for each word.

---

Might look something like this

```
Z = {x: 0 for x in all_english_words}
for x in Z.keys():
    for y in all_foreign_words:
        for s in S:
            Z[x] += <your_function>
```

Comment: I wasn't sure how the double summation notations work. The range of `e_x` is stated as `For each English word ex that appears at least once in our corpus` What would be the order of computation?